# How can I search Github code for a keyword?

Tags: github

I'm a bit flummoxed that I can't find how to do this simple search on Github.

I want to search the code of one of my own repos for a keyword. Surely this is possible?

There is a global search feature but that doesn't seem to do it eg index is about 17 days old and doesn't contain actual code (only results from readme)

Any thoughts? If not maybe there is a 3rd party tool? I'm looking for something that works directly off Github

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> The **git grep** command has a few advantages over normal searching commands like grep and ack. The first is that it’s really fast, the second is that you can search through any tree in Git, not just the working directory. As we saw in the above example, we looked for terms in an older version of the Git source code, not the version that was currently checked out.

[This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Searching) could be what you're searching for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll take a look at this.